# How displaying instances of one class in a representation of another class?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Can you please tell me how to display the list of orders of the company when moving from the general list of companies directly to its profile? Output here: views/companies/show.html.erb

Do not judge strictly, I'm just rolling into RoR. Thanks for understanding :)

Working request example with company id=305:

```
    select o.id
    from orders as o
    inner join users as u ON o.user_id = u.id
    inner join companies as c on c.id = u.company_id
    where c.id = 305
```

models/user.rb:

```
class User < ApplicationRecord  

  belongs_to :company
  has_many :orders

end
```

models/order.rb

```
class Order < ApplicationRecord  

  belongs_to :user
  
end
```

models/company.rb:

```
class Company < ApplicationRecord  

  has_many :users

end
```

users_controller.rb:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
  end

  def index
    @users = User.paginate(page: params[:page]) 
  end   
  
end
```

orders_controller.rb:

```
class OrdersController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @orders = Order.find(params[:id])    
  end
    
  def index
    @orders = Order.paginate(page: params[:page]) 
  end 

end
```

companies_controller.rb

```
class CompaniesController < ApplicationController

  def show
    @company = Company.find(params[:id]) 
  end
    
  def index
    @companies = Company.paginate(page: params[:page]) 
  end 

end
```

views/companies/index.html.erb:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <%= will_paginate %>
      <h1>Company list</h1>
        <ul class='companies'>
          <% @companies.each do |company| %>
            <li>
              <%= link_to company.full_name, company %> 
            </li>
          <% end %> 
        </ul>
      <%= will_paginate %>
      <html>
```

views/companies/show.html.erb:

```
      <!DOCTYPE html>
      <html>
      <div>id: <%= @company.id %></div>
      <div>Register date: <%= @company.created_at %></div>
      <div>Name: <%= @company.full_name %></div>
      <html>
```

Works in console

```
orders = Order.joins(user: :company).where(companies: { id: 305 })
```

Comment: You don't need "Ruby on Rails" in the title since you have a tag for that.

Comment: Order.joins(users: :company).where(company: {id: id})

Answer (score -1, accepted):

For example another way (this is a pattern), its working:

1. Add to companies controller @orders:

```
def show
    @company = Company.find(params[:id]) 
    @orders = Order.joins(user: :company).where(companies: { id: params[:id] })
  end
```

2. Add code to show.html.erb:

```
<div>
Order list of company:
  <% @orders.each do |order| %>
    <li>
      <%= link_to order.id, order %> 
    </li>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

First add the missing definition of the association between companies and orders, like this:

```
# in app/models/company.rb
has_many :users
has_many :orders, through: :users
```

Then can just call `@company.orders` to get the list of `orders` associated with `@company`.

For example, in your `views/companies/show.html.erb` like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <div>id: <%= @company.id %></div>
  <div>Register date: <%= @company.created_at %></div>
  <div>Name: <%= @company.full_name %></div>

  <ul>
    <% @company.orders.each do |order| %>
      <li>order <%= link_to(order.id, order) %></li> 
    <% end %>
  </ul>
<html>
```

Comment: This will absolutely work; however, you should probably load the orders in the controller. IMO views making DB calls is a no go.

Comment: Interesting, @engineersmnky. IMHO controllers should only initialize as little instance variables as possible (preferred only one). And therefore, I would not suggest initializing an`@orders` variable in the controller in this example. Btw. even if there was `@orders = @company.orders` in the controller, that would only create a relation, the actual db call would still happen in the view when `each` is called.

Comment: First I would like to preface with this is my opinion: You are correct that the query is not technically executed until `each`; however `@company.orders` in the view is a logical operation and implies that the view knows what a `Company` is. It has always been my perspective that the view should merely present data not formally interact with it. I have no objection to your 1 instance variable and I am a huge proponent of service objects or decorators for this reason. The logic then exists in the object and not in the view, which I have found makes for more maintainable and extensible code.

Comment: Plus one for service objects and decorators.

Comment: In DB there is only a relationship between tables 'orders' - 'users' and 'users' - 'companies'. Does this method work? Rails

Comment: Yes `has_many ..., through:` is a [thing in Rails](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html#the-has-many-through-association).